# Reddit API from jQuery ajax with CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, cors, reddit

I'm trying to access the reddit API using jQuery's ajax features. From what I've seen online, this code that I'm using should be able to do CORS:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://reddit.com/api/login",
    data: {
        api_type:"json",
        passwd:"MyRedditPassword",
        rem:false,
        user:"MyRedditUsername"
    },
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data){console.log("success:",data);},
    error:function(error){console.log("error:",error);},
    crossDomain:true,
    xhrFields:{withCredentials:true}
});
```

This is accessing [this part of reddit's API](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_login).

I get the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

It is to my understanding that this error comes about as a problem on the server's end; their response to my request doesn't have a header which is necessary for CORS. This would just mean that reddit's API doesn't support CORS. [However, the reddit admins said here that they have implemented CORS support](http://www.reddit.com/r/changelog/comments/1r0u3v/reddit_change_third_party_websites_can_now_make/).

What's wrong with my request, that makes it so that I try to use a feature they say they support but I'm getting a response that says they don't support it? Do I need to do something different in my request to make reddit send back the CORS header?

Comment: trying to get CORS to work, not JSON-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the post that you linked:

> We now support CORS in addition to JSONP for **unauthenticated** cross-domain requests to the reddit API

Emphasis mine - CORS isn't supported for authenticated requests.

Comment: what exactly does that mean? (unauthenticated vs authenticated) -- thanks for the response by the way

Comment: Also, does this mean that it's just completely impossible to do this API call from client-side javascript? Because the only two ways to do cross-domain requests are JSONP and CORS, and we saw CORS isn't supported, and we know JSONP can't do POST requests... So to do this I'd have to set up a proxy in my host or something?

Comment: Unauthenticated means you can't login. In your question, you're trying to authenticate as a user by POSTing to "http://reddit.com/api/login".

Comment: Thank you. I'd love to know if there is any workaround to this -- I want to access the reddit API via client side JavaScript but I need to get around the origin problem.

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to do that at this time. Browser-based, Javascript only apps have to wait until reddit's OAuth2 implementation supports "implicit" grant types.